# Automate HTTP requests after logging into a secure server

Tags: linux, http, post, automation

I am trying to automate some HTTP posts which will save some time which i need to manually request. The HTTP post request is after logging into a secure website. Could any one suggest ways in which i can achieve this ???

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/) for this purpose. You can view the request you send using Fiddler and the response. Honestly I don't know much about the fiddler behavior when it comes to HTTPS. It might not reveal everything but still it will provide useful information such as headers etc.

Install [Request to Code extension](http://www.chadsowald.com/software/fiddler-extension-request-to-code) for Fiddler and you can generate the code relevant to each request so you can mimic the request in your automation process.

**Update**

You can use [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) for this purpose. Google Chrome Developer tools provide an easy way to build the curl command if you try to mimic a browser behaviour.

[image]

Comment: I am a linux user, Fiddler has a  Windows version. Even though they have an alpha version for Linux, I am sure it would not be the best way. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: @Patrick Updated the answer. Not sure whether you are interested on this anymore though.